# Why printing unsigned char outputs such a great number?

Tags: c, char, printf, unsigned

I am printing variable of type unsigned char (8bits long).
But the `printf()` outputs a huge number outside the range of the variable I am printing.

```
unsigned char c; 
printf("%u",c);
```

The output is:

> 21664

I don't know what is going on?

Comment: you should assign something to it before using it

Answer (score 3):

It has undefined behaviour because `a` is not initialized .

To print decimal value of character you can do like this -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
         unsigned char a='A';
         printf("%d",a);
         return 0;
   }
```

Which will print `ascii` value of `A` that is `65`.

Answer (score 2):

Modify to `printf( "%u", (unsigned int)c )`. Otherwise `printf` will get 2 bytes from stack - one with `c` value and other with random byte.

Comment: or maybe 4 bytes? {**hint: no**}

Comment: Ok, 4 also possible. I come from 16 bit (8086) world :)

Answer (score 2):

because print format is %u is unsigned int,but the c is a unsigned char. printf parse c point as a unsigned int point, program read undefined buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Using wrong format specifier leads to undefined behavior.

`%u` is for `unsigned int` not for `unsigned char`

Answer (score 1):

> The output is: 21664 I don't know what is going on?

To print the value of that char you have to give a value to that char, if not you get undefined behavior.
If you need to print its decimal value, just use %d(%u its ok also here) because CHAR is also an INT

```
printf("The decimal value of CHAR is\t%d",c);
```

This can help you also to understand it:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned char c = 'A';

    printf("The decimal value of CHAR is\t%d\n",c);
    printf("The decimal value of CHAR is\t%u\n",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> The decimal value of CHAR is 65
> The decimal value of CHAR is 65
> ```

Comment: Oh I am sorry. It was my mistake, I saw that stdio.h is missing. After I added that everything works ok. I don't know how it did print text at all.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any error in your code. As far as the length of the printed result is concerned it is printing the value of unsigned int instead of unsigned char. Because of wrong format specifier. The value should be smaller than 65535 and it is.
By the way to print an unsigned char use format specifier %h.
This will tell the compiler that the variable is of type unsigned short and will do the job for you.

Comment: _Because of wrong format specifier_ how is it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

just declare your unsigned char as

```
unsigned char ch=234;
```

and your printf will work correctly